# Showing linear independence of functions $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, solution-verification

I want to show that the functions
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\text{ and } g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1+x_3-x_1-x_4$$
are linearly independent.
Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. It is easy to see that if we want that
$$\alpha(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)+\beta(x_1+x_3-x_1-x_4)=0,$$
$\alpha$ must be equal to $-\beta$. Thus,
$$\alpha(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)-\alpha(x_1+x_3-x_1-x_4)=0$$
$$\implies 2\alpha(x_1+x_4)=0,$$
but this is not true for all $x_1,x_4\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, $\alpha=\beta=0$ and $f,g$ are linearly independent. Looks good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks good to me. A more direct proof is to note that, if $\alpha f+\beta g=0$, then
\begin{aligned}
2\alpha&=\alpha f(1,1,0,0)+\beta g(1,1,0,0)=0,\\
2\beta&=\alpha f(1,-1,0,0)+\beta g(1,-1,0,0)=0.\\
\end{aligned}
Hence $\alpha=\beta=0$ and $f,g$ are linearly independent.